# Best way to match multiple criteria and join

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data that consists of agent names, days and start / end times (example below).

[image: Data]

I'm trying to produce a schedule that automatically updates as the data changes, so the formula needs to take 2 criteria (agent name & day) and return the start and end times, joined into 1 cell and separated by a "-" delimiter (desired output below)

[image: Output]

What would be the best way to approach this? I've tried adding a helper column that includes the agent name and day then using a vlookup however this causes it to populate the adjacent cell. I had similar results using index & match as well.

Comment: Since all rows seem to be unique I think it's a safe bet to start your search with `SUMIFS()` since these seem like numeric data. Then use `TEXT()` to format the result on both ends of the hyphen.

Comment: As mentioned above by @JvdV Sir, yes its much easier with `SUMIFS()` `=TEXT(SUMIFS(data[Start],data[Agent],$A3,data[Date],C$2),"hh:mm;;")&"-"&TEXT(SUMIFS(data[End],data[Agent],$A3,data[Date],C$2),"hh:mm;;;")` perhaps if you are using `MS365` you may try using `MAKEARRAY()` as shown in answers

Answer (score 1):

If Agent is in cell A2, Monday is cell C2 then you can get entire table filled with a single formula:

```
=MAKEARRAY( COUNTA($A$2:$A$1000), 5, LAMBDA( r, c, LET( 
agent, INDEX($A$2:$A$1000,r,1),
day, INDEX($C$2:$G$2,1,c),
data_filtered, FILTER(data, (data[Agent]=agent)*(data[Date]=day) ),
startCol, XMATCH("Start",data[#headers]),
endCol, XMATCH("End",data[#headers]),
output, INDEX(data_filtered,1,startCol) & "-" ^ INDEX(data_filtered,1,endCol),
output ) ) )
```

Comment: Your formula works **correct**, but you need to wrap the last two `INDEX()` within a `TEXT()` Function. `=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA($A$2:$A$1000),5,LAMBDA(r,c,
LET(agent,INDEX($A$2:$A$1000,r,1),
day,INDEX($C$2:$G$2,1,c),
data_filtered,FILTER(data,(data[Agent]=agent)*(data[Date]=day),""),
startCol,XMATCH("Start",data[#Headers]),
endCol,XMATCH("End",data[#Headers]),
output,TEXT(INDEX(data_filtered,1,startCol),"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(INDEX(data_filtered,1,endCol),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR(output,""))))`